# How to present actionSheet properly on left navigation bar on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Im trying to present an actionSheet on an ipad using the left navigationBar item. The problem is left sidebarItem is not considered a view but a UIBarButtonItem so I get an error on runtime using the ipad. this code is

...

```
     if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
                        let button = self.LeftBarItem
                        if let currentPopoverpresentioncontroller = alertController.popoverPresentationController{
    //error start here
                            currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.sourceView = button
                            currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.sourceRect = button.bounds;
   error end here //
                            currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up;
                            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }else{
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `UIPopoverPresentationController`. There's a pretty obvious property to be used.

Comment: And there's no reason to have different code for iPad and iPhone. Use the iPad code you have regardless of device (remove the `if/else`.

Answer (score 0):

This allow the user to present `popoverPresentationController` using the navigationBar Item.

```
 if let popoverController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
                    popoverController.barButtonItem = self.LeftBarItem as? UIBarButtonItem
                }

                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please add more context. What does this code do and how does it answer the question?